# Best way to parse this string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, tokenize

I have a string that is the form of:

```
{'var1':var2}
```

I was able to parse this string so that var1 and var2 are both string variables. However it takes multiple string tokenizer calls, first to split from the ":" and then to extract the data.

So what would be the best (least lines of code) to do this?

Comment: Are the curly brackets part of the string?and Var one in commas and var2 not? Do you or can you use Apache commons or Google Guava?

Comment: that looks eerily similar to JSON...

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: JSON uses double-quotes around all strings.

Comment: *"what would be the best (least lines of code) to do this?"* How many lines does it currently take?  Does that include 'white-space' lines? ..

Comment: @MarkByers hence the eerily remark :)

Comment: yes the curly brackets are part of the string and var1 is surrounded by single quotes, var2 is not

Comment: Is var2 supposed to be the value of var1?

Comment: I assume that var1 and var2 can contain none-escaped ":" and "'", if not its an "easy" regexp ...

Comment: You are asking for a parser but you don't formally describe the language you are trying to parse.  You only give one input.

Comment: If the variables can contain ': then I don't think this is solvable.  There would be no way to tell where the variables begin or end.

Comment: Sometimes *parsing* should be done with a **parser** rather than trying to wedge regex and/or string.split() into the job. If all you're dealing with is this simple string you may be fine, but if you're trying to more fully parse some JSON you're going to run into a wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want an array containing the two values, then you can can do it in two lines by extracting a substring and then splitting on "':".  It would end up looking something like this:

```
s = s.substring(2, s.length()-1);
String[] sarr = s.split("':");
```

If you really wanted a single line of code, you could combine them into:

```
String[] sarr = s.substring(2, s.length()-1).split("':");
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
String yourstring = "{'var1':var2}";
String regex = "\\{'(.+)':(.+)}";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(yourstring);
String var1 = m.group(1);
String var2 = m.group(2);
```

**EDIT**: for the commentators:

String:

```
{'this is':somestring':more stuff:for you}
```

Output:

```
var1 = this is':somestring
var2 = more stuff:for you
```

PS: tested with Perl, don't have Java at hand right now, sorry.

EDIT: looks like Java regex engine does not like `{` unescaped as *user unknown* points out. Escaped it.

Comment: This suffers from __:'__ inside var1 or var2 - but I think thoose cases are unsolvable/undetermined.

Comment: Right, but only the case of ":" inside *var1*

Comment: Correction: even so, it will work. Regexes are greedy if not told otherwise and if the semicolon is between the single quotes there's no confusion. I think the first string can even contain a single quote (not tested)

Comment: That assumes all the instances of ': are in var1.  Some of them may be in var2.  There is no good way to tell.

Comment: Nope, works fine even if there are semicolons on var2. As I said, regexes are greedy if not told otherwise.

Comment: Regex is incapable of parsing/matching arbitrarily nested and escaped quotes. A real parser is required to do that. Regex is satisfactory for this colon-inside-quote problem if it's constructed correctly, as @m0skit0 points out.

Comment: I guess you have to mask the opening {, else it is expected to start an invalid repetition.

Comment: True, didn't notice, but still works fine. I guess it understands it's not repetition because it's not the correct format

Comment: Works fine? Not on my Oracle-JVM-1.6-32bit-linux. :) What do you have?

Comment: Ok, I'll trust your word (and see Java's regexes actually suck xD) Just read the whole answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is unsolvable in the general case.
Consider for example:

case a)

var1=

```
:':':
```

var2=

```
':'
```

The the full original string would be

```
{':':':':':'}
```

case b)
var1=

```
:
```

var2=

```
':':':'
```

the the full original string would be

```
{':':':':':'}
```

So, we need "more information". Depending on your requirements / use case you had to live with the ambiguity, put limitations on the strings, or escape/encode the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Something like ***(fragile - see comment(s))***:

```
// 3 lines..
String[] parts = "{'var1':var2}  ".trim().split("':");
String var1 = parts[0].substring(2,parts[0].length);
String var2 = parts[1].substring(0,parts[1].length-1);
```

Comment: {'this is a colon-and-singlequote-inside-var1:'':uninteresting}

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
String re = "\\{'(.*)':(.*)}";
String var1 = s.replaceAll (re, "$1");
String var2 = s.replaceAll (re, "$2");
```

You need to mask the opening `{`, else you get an java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition